# How do I duplicate a Google Sheet with Apps Script that doesn't copy over the attached script files?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I can duplicate the activespreadsheet to a new file on my Google Drive with App Script ok.  However, it copies the attached scripts.  How can I duplicate the spreadsheet without it bringing in all the Apps Scripts?

I can duplicate the spreadsheet ok.  But when I open the newly duplicated file, it has all my scripts attached.  And the Menus.  I just want to duplicate the spreadsheet only.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy a spreadsheet without scripts:

```
function copySpreadsheetWithoutScripts() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.create(ss.getName());
  dss.getSheets()[0].setName("~~~");
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    sh.copyTo(dss).setName(sh.getName());
  });
  dss.deleteSheet(dss.getSheetByName("~~~"));
}
```

If you wish to copy it to a destination folder

```
function copySpreadsheetWithoutScripts() {
  const df = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.folder1id);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.create(ss.getName());
  dss.getSheets()[0].setName("~~~");
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    sh.copyTo(dss).setName(sh.getName());
  });
  dss.deleteSheet(dss.getSheetByName("~~~"));
  Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": df.getId()}]}, dss.getId())
}
```

Note the latter version requires SpreadsheetApp.getActive() project to be a GCP project.

Comment: Thanks.  this works well.  I added a "return" line to send the spreadsheet object.  Also, I included an argument to write the name, and I added a conditional to exclude the Sheet1 which in my code is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new blank spreadsheet and use `Sheet.copyTo()` to copy each sheet in the source spreadsheet into the new spreadsheet in turn.